# Select records with associated records of specific type

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have 2 tables Booking, Ticket. Ticket.BookingId is foreign key to Booking.Id: 
[image]

*How to write SQL select (compatible with MS SQL Server) for select bookings which has **only** tickets of type 1 or 3 or 7?*

Something as:

```
select Booking.Id
from Booking 
    join Ticket on Ticket.BookingId = Booking.Id
group by Booking.Id
having Ticket.Type IN (1,3,7)
```

For example, in this case:

[image]

final result will: 2,3.

Booking.Id = 1 is not in final result because in table Ticket is ticket (Id = 4, BookingId = 1, Type = 8), so this booking contains also other ticket type than 1 or 3 or 7

Solution in LINQ:

```
var result = (from b in Booking 
join t in Ticket on Booing.Id equals Ticket.BooingId
group new {b,t} by b.Id).Where(group => group.Where(itemOfGroup=>itemOfGroup.Ticket.Type != 1 && itemOfGroup.Ticket.Type != 3 && itemOfGroup.Ticket.Type != 7).Count() == 0 ).Select(group => group.Key);
```

Comment: In case `BookingId: 1` have `Type: 1, 3, 7, 8` . Do we need to return the `BookingId: 1` in the final result or not? Because you mentioned only `1, 3, 7` !

Comment: No. It is essence of my problem. I need in final result only bookings which do not contain other type of ticket than 1,3,7. If booking also contains ticket of type 8 so this booking can not be in final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the booking and take only those groups having no other types

```
select Booking.Id
from Booking 
join Ticket on Ticket.BookingId = Booking.Id
group by Booking.Id 
having sum(case when Ticket.Type NOT IN (1,3,7) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: OP said types "1 _or_ 3 _or_ 7". So I assumed any/all of these types is but no others . Will your query find, for instance, bookings which have type 3 only, or have type 1 and 3, but not 7? It doesn't look like it would, but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You are absolutely right! Changing it right now. Thanks.